# Escaping an apostrophe in golang

Tags: go

How can I escape an apostrophe in golang?
I have a string

```
s = "I've this book"
```

and I want to make it

```
s = "I\'ve this book"
```

How to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If it's to escape data for some further operations there might be a more specific way to do it rather than a simple string replace. Tell more about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to insert this string as a value in a cassandra table via insert query.

Comment: Ah-ha. As I expected. Doesn't whatever database you're using support parametrized queries? Building queries or other data structures via string manipulation is troublesome not to mention easy to mess up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escaping a character is only necessary if it can be interpreted in two or more ways. The apostrophe in your string can only be interpreted as an apostrophe, escaping is therefore not necessary as such. This is probably why you see the error message `unknown escape sequence: '`.

If you need to escape the apostrophe because it is inserted into a database, first consider using library functions for escaping or inserting data directly. Correct escaping has been the culprit of many security problems in the last decades. **You will almost certainly do it wrong**.

Having said that, you have to escape `\` to do what you want ([click to play](http://play.golang.org/p/YibyDOs7KE)):

```
fmt.Println("\\'") # outputs \'
```

As you're using cassandra, you can use packages like [gocql](https://github.com/tux21b/gocql) which provide you with parametrized queries:

```
session.Query(`INSERT INTO sometable (text) VALUES (?)`, "'escaping'").Exec();
```

Comment: stmt := "INSERT INTO reviews (review_id,product_id,user_email,title,review,upcount,downcount,score,anonymous,reply_to,creation_date) VALUES ('" + review_id + "','" + product_id + "','" + email_id + "','" + title + "','" + review_text+"',"+strconv.Itoa(0) + "," + strconv.Itoa(0) + "," + strconv.Itoa(0)+"," + strconv.FormatBool(anonymous)  + ",''" + ",dateof(now()));"                                                     I am using gocql, and the above query gives Unknown escape sequence: ' when either review column consist of ' in its string.

Comment: @tushR Use parametrized queries and a library like gocql. Your code is not safe.

Comment: ok,got it..will use parameterized queries. Thanks @MattiVirkkunen